# Suspicious powershell script Microsoft Defender for Cloud

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I'm running a PowerShell script to mount an Azure storage account fileshare via the DevOps release pipeline and the script is supposed to create a scheduled job on the target machine.

**The script is running fine** and **Fileshare is being got mounted** but the Azure security center is flagging the whole script as ***Suspicious powershell script***.

```
$user = '`"localhost\testuser`"'
$fileShare = '`"testsa.file.core.windows.net`"'
$Secret = ConvertTo-SecureString $(SAKey) -AsPlainText -Force

Write-Host "Adding Testuser2 SA to Admin group"
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "Domain\Testuser2"

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -command "& {$connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName testsa.file.core.windows.net -Port 445
if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded)
{
    # Save the password so the drive will persist on reboot
    cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add:$fileShare /user:$user /pass:$Secret
}
else
{
    Write-Error -Message "Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445. Check to make sure your organization or ISP is not blocking port 445, or use Azure P2S VPN, Azure S2S VPN, or Express Route to tunnel SMB traffic over a different port."
}}"'

$time = Get-Date
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $time.AddMinutes(1)

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "AddFileShare" -Description "Add file share for replication" -User "Domain\Testuser2" -Password "$(Testuser2Password)" -RunLevel Highest -Force 

Write-Host "Waiting for 70s"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 70

Write-Host "Removing Testuser2 SA from Admin group"
Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "Domain\Testuser2"
```

What could be the reason or what changes should I do to make it not being flagged as a suspicious script, also I don't want to create a suppression rule in Azure security center to suppress this alert.

Comment: Adding and removing members for the Administrators group?

Comment: I want to execute this task under a different account and that account is a service account.

Comment: Why don't you perform the add to admin group step manually, then remove that code from the script and see if the warning goes away

Comment: I assume the service account would need to be a privileged account anyway in order to add a user to the admin group.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have tried adding the Service account manually also but that didn't help with the Security alert.

Comment: Ids `Domain\Testuser2` the service account? Did you remove this line from the script: `Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "Domain\Testuser2"`?

Comment: Yes, I did remove it as part of my own testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone comes back to this

I had to change the Task schedulers argument to a smaller chunk of code and the security alert was no more coming up.